# Simplified the condition in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, if-statement

The code below needs three lines. Is it possible to simplified to one line?

```
code = [x for x in code if not 'W' in x]
code = [x for x in code if not '06501' in x]
code = [x for x in code if not '06502' in x]
```

I was trying this but did not work

```
code = [x for x in code if not 'W' or if not '06501' or if not '06502' in x]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: can you update sample of code variable, what its look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
code = [x for x in code if not ('W' in x or '06501' in x or '06502' in x)]
```

This works for the following input:

```
code = [['W'],['06501'],['06502'],["hi"]]
code = [x for x in code if not ('W' in x or '06501' in x or '06502' in x)]
# >> code: [['hi']]
```

You could also use an array like so:

```
disallowed_values = ['W', '06501', '06502']

code = [ x for x in code if not any(y in x for y in disallowed_values)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Better you can do like this:

```
remove_item = ['w', '06501', '06502']
code = [x for x in code if x not in remove_item]
```

Comment: This is not the same OP requirement. You are checking if `x` matches any item in `remove_item`. OP's requirement if any any item in `remove_item` occurs in `x`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work on the test case in my answer - returns all items.

Comment: I did in my answer. I'm not OP, so my test case could be wrong, but it worked with the original code OP provided. (`code = [['W'],['06501'],['06502'],["hi"]]`)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it

```
[ x for x in code if not any( i in x for i in ['W', '06501', '06502'])]
```

An alternate version

```
[ x for x in code if not any(map(lambda i: i in x, remove_items)) ]
```

Modifying the same to use filter

```
filter(lambda x: not any(map(lambda i: i in x, remove_items)), code)
```

Note: The choice of which semantic to use is mostly personal preference. However the last version may be better is `code` is large since it returns a generator object for lazy evaluation (in python3)